# Retrieve product localised price - Unexpected non-void return value in void function

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, storekit, swiftystorekit

I am using [SwiftyStoreKit](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit) to implement iAP within my project. I have a auto-renewable subscription that users can purchase and restore. This seems to work fine however I am having issues when retrieving the product information to display to the UI.

I am trying to get the localised price to display, the price returned is the yearly cost so I need to divide the number by 12 to also display it as a monthly cost. However when getting the price and trying to return to value I get the following error:

> Unexpected non-void return value in void function

**Setting the button value**

```
let subscribeButton = subscriptionManager.getSubscriptionPricePerMonth(isYearly: false)
subscribeButton(monthlyCost, for: .normal)
```

**Retrieving the price**

```
//Get prices

func getSubscriptionPricePerMonth() -> String {
    let productId = getProductId()


    NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.networkOperationStarted()
    SwiftyStoreKit.retrieveProductsInfo([productId]) { result in
        NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.networkOperationFinished()

        if let product = result.retrievedProducts.first {

            let priceString = product.localizedPrice!
            return priceString
        } else if let invalidProductId = result.invalidProductIDs.first {
              //return ("Could not retrieve product info", message: "Invalid product identifier: \(invalidProductId)")
            print("Could not retrieve product info\(invalidProductId)")
        } else {
            let errorString = result.error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error. Please contact support"
            //return ("Could not retrieve product info, \(errorString)")
            print("\(errorString)")

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unexpected non-void return value in void function

Error says, that you are trying to return some value from the void function.

Now, let's understand your case.

Your actual function is

```
func getSubscriptionPricePerMonth() -> String {}
```

which you are expecting to return you some value as a String. But looking at the code inside, there you are using asynchronous block, which has void return type

```
SwiftyStoreKit.retrieveProductsInfo([productId]) { result -> Void in 
  // Here you are returning some values after parsing the data, which is not allowed.
}
```

For returning something out of the block, you can use [DispatchGroup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup) to make it synchronous

Hope this helps.